# Is the end credits sequence real?

Tags: the-lego-movie-2-the-second-part

In *The Lego Movie 2*, the end credits scene featuring a big rolling cylinder reminded me of the [Lego Kinetic Sculptures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sng5xg4wDuc). It looked a bit more real than the whole movie, which is CGI made to look like real life and I am wondering if it was actually a real thing build, like the kinetic sculptures? Is it real? And is there any specific person responsible for designing this huge lego build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end credits were a mixture of practical effects and CGI, designed and animated by [Alma Mater studios](https://www.am.tv/featured) using Lego "kinetic sculptures" and stop-motion photography.

> Sitting with our fellow bloggers, ThatsItLA had a chance to talk to
> directors Mike Michelle and Trisha Gum about the film. That’s when I
> asked about how they came up with the end credits for The LEGO Movie
> 2. Rather than just repeat themselves, the LEGO team came up with a very elaborate sequence that involved two wheels of LEGOs, one side
> would rotate clockwise, while the other would rotate counterclockwise.
> Each side would have a character and their counterpart meet in the
> middle where they would join hands.
>
> Mitchell described it as “Insane.” He added, “that was one guy made
> that in a warehouse somewhere. Is that not incredible?”
>
> So I asked him how they came up with it since it is so much different
> from the original and their spinoffs.  The key thing to know about
> this end credits sequence is that it is all very real. “Isn’t it super
> creative? Super creative,” Mitchell said. “That–just–it started with a
> very simple conversation where we’re like–they pitched it to us and
> then we’re like, ‘We want to make this real thing that could actually
> be built.’ And they just asked us about our movie because our movie
> wasn’t done yet. We’re halfway done. And we’re like, ‘This is really a
> movie about contrast, and like characters that don’t fit together.’
> And I think we did a few sketches of like little sketches like an old
> man with a baby, you know, and just like the contrast. And that’s all
> they had was a few posted notes. And then those guys went and built
> that thing.”
>
> <sub><sup>[The LEGO Movie 2: The Second Part Directors Talk About That Awesome And Very Real End Credits Sequence](https://thatsitla.com/the-lego-movie-2-the-second-part-directors-talk-about-that-awesome-and-very-real-end-credits-sequence/)</sup></sub>

and

> This title sequence, set to an amazing song by Beck feat. Robyn & The
> Lonely Island, explores a rotating drum of kinetic LEGO sculptures
> that celebrate themes from the film.
>
> <sub><sup>[ALMA MATER - THE LEGO MOVIE 2 “MAIN ON END TITLES”](https://www.am.tv/featured)</sup></sub>